# Check for button interaction while awaiting for message (Nextcord)

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I'm making a discord slash command that I need for another projext that once interacted with starts looking for images sent by the user in the chat and saves them. It all works fine, but when I interact with the button to stop looking for images the loop has already checked event.is_set() != True at 2 lines after #HELP HERE and is awaiting for a message, so even if the loop is closed I get one more iteration. Is there a way to stop this code:

```
check = lambda msg: interaction.user.id == msg.author.id
message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

from running even if it has already started awaiting?

This is the full code without the @bot.slash_command() decorator:

```
async def auto(interaction:Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    embed = Embed(title="", color=0x2f3136)
    #Make a screenshot with Win+Shift+S and press Ctrl+V on the chat to send it.
    embed.add_field(name = "", value="Make a screenshot with `Win+Shift+S` and press `Ctrl+V` on the chat to send it.", inline= False)
    stop_button = Button(label="Stop", style = ButtonStyle.red)
    async def stopb_callback(interaction):
        event.set()
    stop_button.callback = stopb_callback
    view = View()
    view.add_item(stop_button)
    message_to_delete = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, view = view)

    #HELP HERE
    while event.is_set() != True:
        print("Event:",event.is_set())
        if event.is_set() != True:
            check = lambda msg: interaction.user.id == msg.author.id
            message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
            
            if len(message.attachments) > 0:
                print(message.attachments[0].url)
                url = message.attachments[0].url
                #save image
                r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                imageName = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.png'
                with open(imageName, 'wb') as out_file:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
            
            else:
                embed1 = Embed(title="", color=0x2f3136)
                embed1.add_field(name = "", value="You have to send a screenshot to start.", inline= False)
                message1 = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed1)
                all_messages.append(message1)
```

I also tried assigning a variable like stop = False before the loop and assigning it the value True in the stopb_callback function but it doesn't seem to work I'm not sure why that's why I used asyncio.Event().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution:

`message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)`

this wait_for function when running continuously check for 2 things:

the event, in this case "message" and for the check, in this case:

`check = lambda msg: interaction.user.id == msg.author.id`

so, by adding to the add function an and statement that looks like this:

`check = lambda msg: interaction.user.id == msg.author.id and not stop`

the function while waiting for the message checks that the I pressed the stop button, and so the check is no more equal to True, but now it's equal to False, so stops searching for that message.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, that's a doozy of a problem you've got there! But don't worry, I'm here to help.

So, you're trying to stop a loop that's in the middle of waiting for a message, and you're finding that it still gets one more iteration even after you've closed the loop.

Well, one way you could solve this is by using asyncio.Event(). The way this works is that you can set the event, which then cancels the wait_for(). However, you've already tried this and it's not working for you.

What about trying a different approach? Maybe you could create a flag variable, let's call it stop, that you can set to True when the stop button is interacted with. Then, in the loop, you can check the value of the stop variable before each iteration and break out of the loop if it's set to True.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
async def auto(interaction:Interaction):
await interaction.response.defer()
stop = False
embed = Embed(title="", color=0x2f3136)
#Make a screenshot with Win+Shift+S and press Ctrl+V on the chat to send it.
embed.add_field(name = "", value="Make a screenshot with `Win+Shift+S` and press `Ctrl+V` on the chat to send it.", inline= False)
stop_button = Button(label="Stop", style = ButtonStyle.red)
async def stopb_callback(interaction):
    nonlocal stop
    stop = True
stop_button.callback = stopb_callback
view = View()
view.add_item(stop_button)
message_to_delete = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, view = view)

#HELP HERE
while not stop:
    print("Event:",event.is_set())
    check = lambda msg: interaction.user.id == msg.author.id
    message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    
    if len(message.attachments) > 0:
        print(message.attachments[0].url)
        url = message.attachments[0].url
        #save image
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        imageName = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.png'
        with open(imageName, 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
    
    else:
        embed1 = Embed(title="", color=0x2f3136)
        embed1.add_field(name = "", value="You have to send a screenshot to start.", inline= False)
        message1 = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed1)
        all_messages.append(message1)
```

Try this out and see if it solves your problem! If not, let me know and I'll see if there's another solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I just tried it out, and it does stop the loop, but not the: `await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)`, it still gets that last iteration and doesn't stop it. What else can I try?

Comment: Found a solution, thanks for helping anyway!